# Помогите с парсингом страницы

Tags: python, парсер

Не получатеся спарсить данные о голах с сайта melbet. Идея в том, чтобы бот брал с этой страницы любой матч (они постоянно обновляются, но суть одна и та же):

```
https://melbet.ru/live/football/
```

Для примера я возьму первый сайт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот здесь начинается функция, с которой мне нужна помощь:

Бот переходит по ссылке к самому матчу (просто получает её из атрибута href через selenium)

И теперь он должен просто счет матча и вывести в консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня почему-то не получается это сделать.

Структура функции должна быть примерно следующая

```
def check(ссылка для проверки счета):    #https://melbet.ru/live/football/118737-japan-j-league/390516811-tokyo-shimizu-s-pulse/
    # здесь он как-то парсит счет
    print(score)
```

Для меня это уже просто дело принципа: разобраться, как можно это спарсить. Помогите пж с реализацией

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, сделал, анализируя xhr запросы